# Backbone app saving to localstorage but no mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, backbone.js, local-storage

I have my app working successfully with localstorage and I have set up mongodb on my machine and can insert data etc. however when I try to save the data to mongodb nothing happens. I'm thinking its not conecting but not sure.

This is where I change from localstorage to mongodb

```
   bb.model.Items = Backbone.Collection.extend(_.extend({    
     model: bb.model.Item,
     // localStorage: new Store("items"),
    url: '/api/rest/todo',
```

from what I can tell, this should be the only change in the backbone app. This code resides in
C:\work\ToDo\site\public\js.

The html file resides in C:\work\ToDo\site\public

I have my server code here 
       http://jsbin.com/akacif/2/watch
which I'm running from C:\work\ToDo\node\lib

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the [idAttribute](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute) of your model correctly?

From the documentation,

> A model's unique identifier is stored under the id attribute. If
>   you're directly communicating with a backend (CouchDB, MongoDB) that
>   uses a different unique key, you may set a Model's idAttribute to
>   transparently map from that key to id.

```
var Meal = Backbone.Model.extend({
  idAttribute: "_id"
});

var cake = new Meal({ _id: 1, name: "Cake" });
alert("Cake id: " + cake.id);
```

Comment: I have the following code on my server. I was hoping this would convert the id's 
util.fixid = function( doc ) {
  if( doc._id ) {
    doc.id = doc._id.toString()
    delete doc._id
  }
  else if( doc.id ) {
    doc._id = new mongodb.ObjectID(doc.id)
    delete doc.id
  }
  return doc
}